# Every triangulation of an oriented matroid is partitionable

Tags: reference-request, simplicial-complexes, oriented-matroids

In his unpublished article, *Combinatorial properties of triangulations of oriented matroids*, Julian Webster proves that every triangulation of an oriented matroid is partitionable.

Does this result appear somewhere in the published literature? If so, where?

Edits:

1. Webster himself does not know if this result has been published
   elsewhere.
2. Two excellent resources for triangulations of oriented matroids are [*Triangulations: Structures for Algorithms and Applications*](https://books.google.at/books?redir_esc=y&id=SxY1Xrr12DwC&q=oriented%20matroid#v=snippet&q=oriented%20matroid&f=false) in the realizable case and [*Triangulations of Oriented Matroids*](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/c302/3482d452d7f67874404345792dd0b0a8ed30.pdf) in the general case. Neither of these sources discuss partitions of triangulations of oriented matroids.
3. A [simplicial complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex) $\Delta$ is **partitionable** if there is a function $\phi : F \to \Delta$ on the facets of $\Delta$ such that the set of intervals $\{[\phi(f), f]~|~f \in F\} $ is a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) of the faces of $\Delta$.

Comment: Can you please define what do you mean by partitionable?

Comment: Partitionable means "partitionable as an abstract simplicial complex on the set of all one-simplices in the triangulation". For the definition of partitionable simplicial complex see Definition 2.5 in this article: https://arxiv.org/abs/1504.04279.

Comment: Since I am an author of the two "excellent sources" I should give my opinion: no, as far as I know this is not published. When I was writing the "Triangulations of Oriented Matroids" paper I thought about this and the way I recall it (this was 20 years ago) is that at some point I thought I had a proof but then was not convinced by it and left the question out of the paper.